# Sorting an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Language: Ruby

I have an array of Products. Each Product has an attribute called product_price_name.

[Product.product_price_name = "All Prices", Product.product_price_name = "$1 to $100" ]

I want to sort this array so the first result is "All Prices" and then the next options will be price ranges such as $1- $100, $100- $200

Comment: You already have a question for this (where you already accepted an answer). Please don't spread one question out this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# some setup
Product = Struct.new(:product_price_name)
array = %w{$1-100 $200-1000 All_Prices $100-200}.collect{|each|Product.new(each)}

# the actual code
array = array.sort_by { |each| each.product_price_name }
array.unshift array.pop
array # => [#<struct Product product_price_name="All_Prices">, #<struct Product product_price_name="$1-100">, #<struct Product product_price_name="$100-200">, #<struct Product product_price_name="$200-1000">]
```

Gosh, one should never submit code that had never run! Mea culpa.

Comment: I have never seen this method before and I'm not a really great programmer. Can you please give me a copy and past code to put on this array [Product.product_price_name = "All Prices", Product.product_price_name = "$1 to $100" ].

Comment: oops, wrong syntax, my bad. It is `array.sort_by` and not `array sort_by:` (programming too much Pharo today).